# Many to many on delete cascade relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have an entity called Profile. This entity can be followed or follow other Profiles.

```
public class Profile{

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "profile_fans")
public Set<Profile> fansFollowed;

}
```

I want to delete a Profile, and it throws me this error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`profile_fans`, CONSTRAINT `FK48ECA896ADDBF9EF` FOREIGN KEY (`fansFollowed_id`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`))

I want to delete only the relation between Profiles. Not the entity.

Is this possible?

Comment: In Many to Many you have to have a profile in a set and vice versa, when you want to remove, remove both ! the profile from the set and the set from the profile .
This is if you have bidirectional relation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there was a better solution. This is what I did, maybe help somebody:

```
List<Profile> followers=JPA.em().createQuery(
    "select p from " + Profile.class.getName() + " p " + 
    "join p.fansFollowed f where f.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", profile.id)
    .getResultList();
for (Profile follower : followers) {
    follower.fansFollowed.remove(profile);
    follower.save();
}
profile.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make addProfile and removeProfile that adds and removes from the set